# Reset System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Tags: c#

Am trying to reset the timer using Start() and Stop(), however the functioning is not proper as 2 timers are simultaneously running. please help if some other method can be used

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do you need. Post some source code, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a method with 1 argument that takes in a Timer object. Inside the method you can 'Start()' or 'Stop()'.  Also Each Timer has a unique Name/Id.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have two or more timer events on a windows message queue.  I think handler should be written in such a way that it doesn't matter.